# Get probability on regression value of RandomForestRegressor in scikit

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn, random-forest

For classification problems, RandomForest gives a probability estimate for the class it predicts, using the predict_proba function. Is it possible to get the same for regression problems as well?

Comment: you cannot hope for that, because probability doesn't work the same way in the continuos case: the probability of observing exactly one value is always zero. You need are more complicated concept of confidence in this case: e.g. what is the probability that the value lies inside a certain interval. I am not sure if random forests can do that.

Comment: @cel Any idea which model I can use to get that? I need some kind of confidence score for the value my model is giving as the output?